# Rename files from .txt list

Tags: filenames, rename

I've got .txt list with files and corresponding MD5 hash:

```
ab16d9ab5682bb0038c901ad8fc424c0 *file1.doc
28bb8e092301340f19585201166e5b86 *file2.doc
5f53d5e9512a717049185fcf617b8a37 *file3.doc
3c28de2b988ce82b04803671540427e5 *file4.doc
75079fb178347e3f1b3b886589ca6471 *file5.doc
```

When .txt file is in directory:

1. How to rename files to their hashes?
2. How to rename hashes to their filenames?

Comment: Are your files really named `*file1.doc`? Is the `*` part of the file name?

Comment: @terdon `*` is a flag that `md5sum` uses to indicate a binary file I think

Comment: @steeldriver ah, OK. In that case, we'd need to remove it. Thanks

Comment: For clarification, would you mind editing the post to add the desired output for the input example you showed?

Comment: Thanks @αғsнιη. Working now after remove 'echo'. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to rename files to their hashes?**

```
while IFS=' ' read <&3 -r hash fileName; do
    echo mv -v -- "${fileName#\*}" "${hash}";
done 3< infile.txt
```

**How to rename hashes to their filenames?**

```
while IFS=' ' read <&3 -r hash fileName; do
    echo mv -v -- "${hash}" "${fileName#\*}";
done 3< infile.txt
```

**note**: remove `echo` when you were happy with dry-run. `-v` is a non-standard extension supported by some `mv` implementations to tell them to be more verbose. If your `mv` doesn't support it, just remove it.

We open `infile.txt` on file descriptor 3 instead of stdin (0) so that it doesn't interfere with `mv` user prompting, if any.